# updating to sql failed

Tags: javascript, php, sql-update, edit

I've got an error says failed, whenever I check this code I feel there is nothing wrong with my code. Please help me, as I'm only a beginner. There are forms, javascript, and php.

```
<?php   
    $species="";    //declare variable to assign table record data
    $age= ""; 
    $sex="";
    $location="";
    $comment="";

    require('connectdb.php');
    $record=$_REQUEST['id' ]; 
    $query="SELECT * FROM usersform WHERE  id = $record "; // listing reservation record
    $result=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $species= $row['species'];    //retrieve  table record and assign  to variable 
    $age= $row['age']; 
    $location= $row['location']; 
    $comment= $row['comment']; 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
    {
        //get data from reservation form 
        $spec=$_POST['species'];
        $eage=$_POST['age'];
        $gender=$_POST['gender'];
        $elocation=$_POST['location'];
        $ecomment=$_POST['comment'];

        //update data to table
        $query="    UPDATE `usersform` SET 
                        `species` ='$spec',
                        `age`='$eage',
                        `location`='$elocation',
                        `comment`='$ecomment',
                    WHERE usersform= $record        
                ";
        $qresult = mysql_query($query);

        if ($qresult){
            /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">
            window.location = "http://www.example.com/";
            </script>';*/
            echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location="gallery.php";</script>';
            #header("location:gallery.php"); // redirect to list
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('failed!')</script>";
        }
    }
```

?>

Here is my form code:

```
<h2>Edit/Update Reservation Record </h2>
<form  name="Form" method="Post"  onsubmit="return(validateForm());" onreset="cancel();">
<table cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr>
        <td>species: </td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="species" size="35" value="<?php echo $species; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>age:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="age" maxlength="15" size="15" value="<?php echo $age; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>sex:</td>
        <td><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" value="<?php echo $sex; ?>"/>Male &nbsp; <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" value="<?php echo $sex; ?>"/>Female</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>location:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="location" size="35" value="<?php echo $location; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>comment:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="comment" size="50" value="<?php echo $comment; ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" /></td>
            <td><input type="reset" value="Cancel" name="reset" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
    if( document.Form.species.value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please insert species." );
        document.Form.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    if( document.Form.age.value == "" ||isNaN( document.Form.age.value ) )
    {
        alert( "Please insert age." );
        document.Form.age.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    if( document.Form.location.value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please insert location." );
        document.Form.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
    if( document.Form.comment.value == "" )
    {
        alert( "Please insert comment." );
        document.Form.Name.focus() ;
        return false;
    }
}
function cancel()
{
    window.location.href="gallery.php";
}
```

Comment: int it is my primary key in my database

Comment: You [shouldn't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the red box? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the update syntax is incorrect.. this is the correct sql syntax

```
$query="    UPDATE `usersform` SET 
                        `species` ='$spec',
                        `age`='$eage',
                        `location`='$elocation',
                        `comment`='$ecomment'
                    WHERE usersform= $record        
                ";
```

Answer (score 0):

change your `update` query to this

```
$query="    UPDATE `usersform` SET 
                    `species` ='$spec',
                    `age`='$eage',
                    `location`='$elocation',
                    `comment`='$ecomment'
                WHERE id= $record        
            ";
$qresult = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Note: Learn `mysqli_` or P.D.O as `mysql` is depriciated

Comment: it says You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id= 11' at line 6

Comment: still no improvement :(

Comment: my value in $record is 11... it is integer and it is auto integer

Comment: remove the last comma from the update syntax.. it should be: UPDATE `usersform` SET 
                    `species` ='$spec',
                    `age`='$eage',
                    `location`='$elocation',
                    `comment`='$ecomment'
                WHERE id= $record

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 the invalid comma is after comment='$ecomment' just before the where